# How to facilitate payment between credit card and bank account through Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a way to create a payment between a credit card and a bank account in my iOS app.  I think I've found a way using PayPal's service, but is there a separate API that also could be used for this?

I've tried PayPal's Connect app (can that be used or am I misunderstanding?), but I don't really know how that works yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Stripe](https://stripe.com).

It is similar to Paypal, but it has a bunch of interesting APIs and it's simple to implement.

You are able to [setup a bank account and receive payouts](https://support.stripe.com/questions/bank-account-and-payouts).

[Here](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios)'s the iOS integration guide and a [backend example](https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend) which you can deploy on heroku.

Comment: Hm... right.  But I don't want payments to myself, I want payments to others.  Does Stripe have an API for this too?

Comment: What you need is probably [connect api](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts) with standard account. Users can pay directly another user (or account in General) without you in the middle. You are able to track what happens, but money exchange is just between them. Take a look and let me know if it may satisfy your requirements

Comment: Hmm... that's interesting.  What % do they take from any payment?

Comment: Think it may vary based on country. [Pricing](https://stripe.com/pricing)